# Intellij Kotlin Worksheet

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

When using a Kotlin Worksheet in Intellij, the Results Pane can be made wider or narrower by dragging the "gutter" between the Results pane and the code pane.

But the drag area is very narrow and difficult for me to find. Is there a way to make the drag area wider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I did not find the way.
I have created a ticket to the IDEA Kotlin Plugin project regarding the issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-26923

Thank you!